# What’s the difference between ‘a hundred’ and ‘one hundred’?

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-usage, american-english, spoken-english

For instance, let’s take a look at the next conversation:

A) How many questions does the test have?

B) A hundred.

And the difference between the conversation above and this one:

A) How many questions does the test have?

B) One hundred.

Are both conversations correct? if not, which one is correct?

Answer (score 0):

They are both correct, and mean exactly the same thing.

I can certainly envisage situations where “one hundred” would be preferred; for example, in response to a question such as:

> Q. Did Cruella de Ville steal *one* hundred and one Beagles, or *two* hundred and one?
>
> A. *One* hundred. And it was Dalmatians you idiot, not Beagles.

Or, by contrast:

> Q. How many press ups did you say you do every morning; was it a hundred, or a million?
>
> A. Eh!? What do you think I am, a machine? It was a hundred. Obviously!

But even there, the “a” and “one” forms are pretty much interchangeable.